# T-SQL Automatic Schema Qualifying

Tags: t-sql

I have a simple requirement. Do you guys know the tool(s) that automatically schema qualifies a T-SQL query inside or outside SSMS?

Comment: do you mean while writing the query, or after it is already written?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Red Gate SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) has an option to append the object's schema automatically.

Comment: @Nick: None that I am aware of, but there may be; I have personal experience with SQL Prompt and find it to be worth the money.